# c# Sort list item group without sorting the entire list

Tags: c#, sorting

I have to sort a list of items like the following

```
Order   Category    Data    Type
1       Unknown     NULL    NULL
5       Item        26:59.2 Suspense 
5       Item        35:10.1 General 
5       Item        35:22.6 General 
5       Item        45:24.0 General 
5       Item        02:16.6 General 
5       Item        37:10.4 Bank 
6       Hidden      NULL    NULL
```

And i want to sort by Data the ones with Order = 5 and Type = General but not changing the position for the Bank or Suspense .
I will always have the Order = 5 grouped, but i might have different Types before and after General Type.

Expected result:

```
Order   Category    Data    Type
1       Unknown     NULL    NULL
5       Item        26:59.2 Suspense 
5       Item        02:16.6 General 
5       Item        35:10.1 General 
5       Item        35:22.6 General 
5       Item        45:24.0 General 
5       Item        37:10.4 Bank 
6       Hidden      NULL    NULL
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Sort on what? The Data column? What is the expected sorted result?

Comment: What did your tried and why is it giving problems?

Comment: Equalsk - i have updated the question.

Comment: What happens if the items come in the order Bank -> General -> Suspense -> General? How could you sort that without affecting the positions like you ask?

Comment: How should the algorithm react if there are more blocks with Order == 5? Merge the block and sort or sort every block independently?

Comment: DavidG, the items wont be mixed. I will always have the General grouped toghether.

Comment: Wischi, i wont have many blocks with Order = 5, only one with different Types.

Comment: How many rows? You could split the list into 3 lists - sort the middle one - and merge again.

Comment: What type is `Data`?

Comment: Wischi, i dont know how many rows. @TimSchmelter - string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "obvious" solution is to split the list into 3 sections and sort the middle bit:

```
//First part
var start = things.TakeWhile(t => t.Order != 5 || t.Type != "General");

//Middle part
var middle = things
    .SkipWhile(t => t.Order != 5 || t.Type != "General")
    .TakeWhile(t => t.Order == 5 && t.Type == "General")
    .OrderBy(t => t.Data);

//Last part:
var end = things
    .SkipWhile(t => t.Order != 5 || t.Type != "General")
    .SkipWhile(t => t.Order == 5 && t.Type == "General");
```

And finally merge them into a single list:

```
var merged = start.Concat(middle).Concat(end);
```

Comment: Pls do not do this. There are already methods to sort a part of the list (see my answer) do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @wischi There's no wheel reinvention going on here, and your answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: you iterate through the list three times and allocate twice the memory to do something what could be done with one iteration (find first and last element) and an inplace sort. Why does my post not answer the question?

Comment: @wischi I never said this was the most efficient way, but sometimes readable code trumps speed. Your answer is effectively just a couple of links with no explanation of how to use them.

Comment: pls don't get me wrong, but the predicate Order == 5 && Type == "General" appears five times in a hardcodes form. I don't think thats very readable or maintainable.

Comment: @wischi Well it would be fairly simple extract the expressions too, but that's not the point. Why don't you go write your own solution and then we can compare.

Comment: maybe later - not that easy on my smartphone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can take apart the query with `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` and put it back together with `Concat` after sorting the middle part:

```
items.TakeWhile(item => item.Order != 5 || item.Type != "General").Concat(
    items.SkipWhile(item => item.Order != 5 || item.Type != "General")
        .TakeWhile(item =>  item.Order == 5 && item.Type == "General")
        .OrderBy(item => item.Date)).Concat(
    items.SkipWhile(item => item.Order != 5 || item.Type != "General")
        .SkipWhile(item => item.Order == 5 && item.Type == "General"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

```
list = list.OrderBy(i => i.Order).ThenByDescending(i => i.Type).ThenBy(i => i.Data);
```

Comment: This way will change Bank with the Suspense and i dont want.

Comment: I edited my answer to change the order done on the **Type** property.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are reinventing the wheel and performance nightmares. Some LINQ ansers are iterating through the list multiple times.

There are already methods to do this!
Find the first element. Find the length of the block and then use:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad(v=vs.110).aspx

or

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14at654h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is a lot of code if i want to get the first match, the last match, split the lists, sort the one i need and merge them.